# Parse meta tag and get HTML content from body with Tika

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-tika

I parse files with the great Apache Tika library. I want to extract the metatags with my own parser and then get the content only from the `<body>`-tag as HTML and store it in a database.

I have tried this now for hours/days :-(, but cannot find a solution:

- When I use the `ToHTMLContentHandler` *after* the `<body>`-tag I get exceptions with an invalid namespace without the `<html>`-tag.
- `BodyContentHandler` just returns the body text without HTML tags.
- The `tika-app` seems to use a `TransformerHandler` to get HTML (I have never heard of this kind of handlers before.) Can I use this to just get the HTML from the `<body>`-tag and parse the meta-tags myself? Is this a better way than to use a `ToHTMLContentHandler`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if following links help you a bit..

[Content Detection, Metadata and Content Extraction with Apache Tika](http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/content-detection-metadata-and-content-extraction-with-apache-tika/)

[Parsing HTML with Apache Tika](http://chrisjordan.ca/post/15219674437/parsing-html-with-apache-tika)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know these interesting articles, but they don't solve my problem. I ended using the `TransformerHandler` which works also after the `<body>` tag when I am faking the `<html>`-start element.

Comment: Glad to here that ! If you have got some solution for your question you may post it here and mark this thread as 'Answered'. So, others with similar question can get reference from here.

Comment: It's difficult to post  a general version of my solution and it's just a hack. If anybody else has a similar problem I would advice him to look at the source of the `tika-app` and read more about XSLT processing.